# Need help creating foreign keys sql error 1215

Tags: mysql, database, reference

Hello my appologies for asking aid but i'm having a little issue in a database adding references

so i got a table

```
CREATE TABLE `kooien` (
`kooiid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`kooidlistppg` INT(11) NULL,
`quarantaine` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
`idvogelsoort` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`idvogelondersoort` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`vasteoflossekooie` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
`bezetofniet` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
`idlistsponsor` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`kooiid`),
INDEX `idvogelsoort` (`idvogelsoort`),
INDEX `idvogelondersoort` (`idvogelondersoort`),
INDEX `kooien_ibfk_4_idx` (`idlistsponsor`),
CONSTRAINT `kooien_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idvogelsoort`) REFERENCES `vogelsoort` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `kooien_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`idvogelondersoort`) REFERENCES `ondersoort` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `kooien_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`idlistsponsor`) REFERENCES `personen` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_kooien_kooientoppg` FOREIGN KEY (`kooidlistppg`) REFERENCES `kooientoppg` (`id`))
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Which appears like

```
kooiid|kooidlistppg|quarantaine|idvogelsoort|idvogelondersoort|Vasteoflossekooien|bezetofniet|lijstlist sponsor
```

Now my problem is making kooidlistppg references to kooidlistppg(id)
i do so with this query

```
ALTER TABLE `kooien`
DROP INDEX `FK_kooien_kooientoppg`,
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_kooien_kooientoppg` FOREIGN KEY (`kooidlistppg`) REFERENCES `kooientoppg` (`id`);
/* SQL Fout (1215): Cannot add foreign key constraint */
```

ill add the create query for the table

```
CREATE TABLE `kooientoppg` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`idpapegaaien` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

please know that its lack of a primary key is to convert a list to a mysql database

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), details of FOREIGN KEY errors with InnoDB can be checked with the following SQL command:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

For example:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2017-01-22 23:43:46 0x7fc9fc0f1700 Error in foreign key constraint of table test/kooien:
 FOREIGN KEY (`kooidlistppg`) REFERENCES `kooientoppg` (`id`))
 COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
 ENGINE=InnoDB:
 Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
 referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
 in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
 Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
 tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
 cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
 Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for correct foreign key definition.
```

As far as I can tell, adding an index to the referenced column would help:

```
ALTER TABLE kooientoppg ADD INDEX id_idx (id);
```